# How to manage Session in android if an app has multiple logins like fb,google and web service login

Tags: java, android, session, facebook-login, google-signin

My Application has three types of login
1.Normal signup and login using web service
2.Facebook Integration
3.Google Integration
What i need to know is how to manage session with three types of login.I used shared preference for the normal login and i am able manage session with multiple users but need help managing session for with this three types

Comment: For your web service login you can use shared preferences and for for FB and Google there is inbuilt functionality to maintain session in SDK's

Answer (score 1):

you can use SharedPreferences and Gson like below :

```
public class Prefs {

public static void putPref(String key, String value, Context context){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getPref(String key, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(key, null);
 }
}
```

add this to your build.gradle :

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
```

in login(activity or fragment) :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User user = ...; //User Object specify your login type with enum or ...
String json = gson.toJson(user);
```

after store your user

```
 Prefs.putPref("user",json,your context);
```

to get your user

```
 String json = = Prefs.getPref("user",your context);
 User user = null;
 if(json != null)
    user = gson.fromJson(json,User.class);
```